# Unity3D - Cinemachine - Camera rotating issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cinemachine

I have the problem that my camera rotates back a little after a rotation after stopping the mouse.

I use a Cinemachine virtual camera.
The character turns with the camera.

The script did not come from me but it works for the maker.
The script comes from the following playlist.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CS7MudfyDzM&list=PLyBYG1JGBcd1E4CigRSDE9YdH8syiDY6-

[script on character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycckM.png)

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterAiming : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float turnSpeed;
    Camera mainCamera;
    
    public Transform cameraLookAt;
    public Cinemachine.AxisState xAxis;
    public Cinemachine.AxisState yAxis;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        xAxis.Update(Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        yAxis.Update(Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        cameraLookAt.eulerAngles = new Vector3(yAxis.Value, xAxis.Value, 0);

        float yawCamera = mainCamera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, yawCamera, 0), turnSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        Debug.Log(Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, yawCamera, 0), turnSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, im fixed it.
Move the line `cameraLookAt.eulerAngles = new Vector3(yAxis.Value, xAxis.Value, 0);`
to end of the function.

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterAiming : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float turnSpeed;
    Camera mainCamera;
    
    public Transform cameraLookAt;
    public Cinemachine.AxisState xAxis;
    public Cinemachine.AxisState yAxis;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        xAxis.Update(Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        yAxis.Update(Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        float yawCamera = mainCamera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, yawCamera, 0), turnSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        
        cameraLookAt.eulerAngles = new Vector3(yAxis.Value, xAxis.Value, 0);
    }

}
```